# How can I move a matrix down by 1 row and 1 column?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matrix

I was wondering how I can move a matrix in an excel file down one row and one column and then save this new matrix as a new file in the same directory?

Below is the program shown which opens my test excel file:

```
import pandas as pd
main=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/testfile/testing.csv') #Reads the matrix in the excel file
```

The test file contains a 4x3 matrix which somehow when opening in spyder its shown as a 3x3 matrix? why is this also happening.

Thanks.

Comment: First row was read as header. Set headers to None: `pd.read_csv(..., headers=None)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got an error using headers so I changed it to header and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because there is no header row in you CSV file, but Pandas by default expects one. Add `headers=None` to your `read_csv` call to fix that:

```
import pandas as pd
main=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/testfile/testing.csv', headers=None) #Reads the matrix in the excel file
```